Extracting Album Art from mp3
I've created a C# function to extract album art from an mp3 file which seems to work well. Is there a better solution?
This is the function that extracts the album art and returns a Bitmap of the stored album art.
Changing Array.Copy To Buffer.BlockCopy increases performance drastically.
    public static Bitmap ExtractAlbumArtFromMp3(string mp3FilePath)
    {            
        using FileStream fs = new(mp3FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using BinaryReader reader = new(fs);
        while(fs.Position < fs.Length - 128)
        {
            byte[] chunk = reader.ReadBytes(10);
            if (chunk[0] == 'I' && chunk[1] == 'D' && chunk[2] == '3')
            {
                int length = (chunk[6] << 21) | (chunk[7] << 14) | (chunk[8] << 7) | chunk[9];
                chunk = reader.ReadBytes(length);                    
                byte[] result = new byte[length - 68];
                Array.Copy(chunk, 57, result, 0, result.Length);                    
                using MemoryStream ms = new(result);
                return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
            }
            else
            {
                fs.Seek(-9, SeekOrigin.Current);
            }                    
        }
        return null;
    }

